# Magento - Authentication Credentials Invalid

Tags: magento, authentication, credentials

I am having an error trying to make a request:

[image: request error]

Then when I submit I have the next error:

[image: second request error]

The `1003887036428` error report file:

[image: report file]

Recently the system worked like a charm but it has to migrate to another host and this error started to appear in the actual hosting. I dont know why.

Comment: It looks like you need to set the correct SMTP (email) credentials in your system -> configuration settings on the new server.

Comment: like @RobbieAverill said you may have recently installed Aschroder SMTPpro module and credentials over there are invalid.

Comment: Thanks to you both, it worked!